# Email notification issues (iPhone 4S with ios 5.1.1)

Tags: iphone, notifications, mobile-mail

I have 5 email accounts on my iPhone 4S.  One is my work email and is on a Microsoft Exchange.  The other 4 are personal accounts and are Gmail accounts.  I have turned on notifications so I will be notified of incoming emails.  The only account that sends me notifications is my work email.

Apple tells me that all accounts should be sending me notifications and that I may need a technician to complete a software configuration.  I have only had the phone 3 days and Apple wants to charge me $59 for them to reconfigure their software issue.

Has anyone else run into this issue, and if so, how have you been able to work around or correct the problem?

Thanks

Comment: What is email set to in Settings > Notifications? And by notifications, I'm guessing that would mean alerts on the lock screen (like SMS defaults)? If that's the case, as I understand it, those alerts are only appearing for your Exchange account. Do the badges show the correct amount of email? 1 other thing - if you bought the phone new, three days ago, you have at least Apple phone support - you could schedule a Genius app. and they should be able to help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting up your Gmail accounts as "exchange accounts? If not I would recommend doing so. Here is a quick walk trough. http://email.about.com/od/iphonemailtips/ss/Set_Up_Push_Gmail_in_iPhone_Mail_Step_by_Step_Screenshots.htm

Answer (score 0):

Gmail is configured as IMAP by default on iOS. Google conveniently provides an [article](http://support.google.com/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138740) to help configure Push Mail, but it doesn’t work for me. Probably I was doing it wrong or because I turn off data all the time. Cody’s [link](http://email.about.com/od/iphonemailtips/ss/Set_Up_Push_Gmail_in_iPhone_Mail_Step_by_Step_Screenshots.htm) looks useful, but it’s for iOS 3.0.